# Show No data message if no records found in reactjs functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I need to check whether if records are present, then I need to show grid using map function. Else I need to show message "No data". This is my code. I used ternary operator to do so

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
{data.length > 0 ?
  {data.map((activity) => (
      <Grid
        item
        xs={6}
        sm={4}
        md={3}
        lg={3}
        onClick={() => {
          setSpec(activity.spec)
          setActivity(activity)
          handleClickOpen(activity.spec)
        }}
        className={classes.thumbMain}
      >
        <ButtonBase focusRipple className={classes.fullwidthBtn}>
          <Card className={classes.manage}>
            <Box mt={2} mb={1}>
              <Box
                className={classes.mainIcons}
              ></Box>
            </Box>
            <Typography className={classes.cardlabel}>{(activity.name)}</Typography>
          </Card>
        </ButtonBase>
      </Grid>
    ))} 
   : <p>No data</p>
   }
  </Grid>
```

The above code returns following error

> Parsing error: ',' expected : in data.map((activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't wrap `data.map(...)` in braces:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {data.length ? (
    data.map((activity) => (
      <Grid
        item
        xs={6}
        sm={4}
        md={3}
        lg={3}
        onClick={() => {
          setSpec(activity.spec);
          setActivity(activity);
          handleClickOpen(activity.spec);
        }}
        className={classes.thumbMain}
      >
        <ButtonBase focusRipple className={classes.fullwidthBtn}>
          <Card className={classes.manage}>
            <Box mt={2} mb={1}>
              <Box className={classes.mainIcons}></Box>
            </Box>
            <Typography className={classes.cardlabel}>
              {activity.name}
            </Typography>
          </Card>
        </ButtonBase>
      </Grid>
    ))
  ) : (
    <p>No data</p>
  )}
</Grid>;
```

You should wrap JS code in braces only one time to use it in JSX. If you add braces in other braces then you will be getting that error again.

Comment: Woked. Thank you :)